# Form submit using ajax get method to get response back using XMLhttpreq

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this form that a user choose values from two dropdown menu. The options in select comes from js file and are exchange rates list. I have already created the code that should give me the result. But when i console.log it doesnt show anything, but the right data is displayed (echoed) in the php file. Right get is displayed in url also. I guess somewhere in the JS part is something wrong and i cant figure it out, i have already looked at other examples but they are all jquery.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<title>something</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src='plotly.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDoc() {
    var e = document.getElementById("searchlan");
    var from = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var e1 = document.getElementById("searchlan1");
    var to = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "server.php?from="+from+"&to="+to, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="info">

        <h2>Exchange rate</h2>
        <form>
        <p>
        <select id="searchlan" name="from"></select>
        <p>

        <p>
        <select id="searchlan1" name="to"></select>
        <p>

        <button onclick="loadDoc()" > show graph </button>
        </p>
        </form>
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>

</div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```
require_once('index.php');

if(isset($_GET['from']) && isset($_GET['to'])){
    //here i bring data from server using curl, it works fine and echoes the data
    $curl = curl_init();

    //this is the response variable
    $obj= json_decode($response);

    //i structure data

   //Here i make it ready to be used in js

    $data = [ [
        "x" => $x,
        "y" => $y,
        "type" => "scatter"  
    ] ];

    $out = json_encode( $data ); 
    echo "{$out}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <button onclick="loadDoc()" > show graph </button>
> ```

When the submit button is clicked, the `loadDoc` function runs, but before the Ajax response arrives, the form submits and a new page is loaded.

The new page doesn't including the event handler waiting for the Ajax response.

---

Don't use a submit button. Add `type="button"`.

Comment: This gives me the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: row 23 Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: @RezaAhmadi — Then the response isn't valid JSON. Probably something to do with the `require_once('index.php');` you start you PHP with. But that's a completely different problem.

Comment: What could be the cause then? what should i look into closely?

Comment: Again: `require_once('index.php');`

Comment: I removed that row from server.php and im still getting the same error. if thats what you meant

Comment: Then there's nothing obvious in the remaining code which would insert a `<` as the 4th character in the response. Try examining the response so you can figure out what it looks like and therefore what could be outputting it.

Comment: So you mean that the response im making ready in server.php file is not json and therefore the js cant pick it up and find it invalid?

Comment: I found out what was wrong. I had html code after the php in server and when i removed it, it solved my issue. Thank you for pointing direction man! i have been sitting with this for while now!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with help of Quentin. You guys can use this code, but remember to remove all of html that you have after your php code. it causes this error

Uncaught SyntaxError: row 23 Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

if you get this, remove all of your html or anything you have after you echo the data you want to send to JS